# Problem with deleting an object usin Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have entinties Project, ProjectPhase and Task.

```
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "project_gen")
    @Column (name = "project_id", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private Integer projectId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private Collection<ProjectPhase> projectPhases;

}

public class ProjectPhase {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "phase_gen")
    @Column(name = "phase_id", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private Integer phaseId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "phase", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private Collection<Task> tasks;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "project_id")
    private Project project;

public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "tasks_gen")
    @Column(name = "task_id", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private Integer taskId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "phase_id", referencedColumnName = "phase_id")
    private ProjectPhase phase;
```

I'm trying to delete a Projectphase object using jpa .delete(projectPhase) method, the code is executing, but when I look at my db, the "deleted" object is still there. I;m not sure what can be wrong as I don't get any error in console.

I'm getting the ProjectPhase object like this

```
  ProjectPhase phase = projectPhaseRepository.findById(phaseId).orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Can't get phase", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST));
```

Which is not null
And trying to delete

```
projectPhaseRepository.delete(phase);
```

On my function to deleteProjectPhase I'm using
`@Transactional(rollbackFor = Throwable.class)`

Comment: can also post your phaseId of Projectphase object which you are trying to delete ?

Comment: If you are using a transaction you will also need to commit.